# Merging product name & description into same line - Magento

Tags: magento

I've currently got a fairly straight forward product page with the following format:

Product name:

Description
Attribute 1
Attribute 2 etc

Now I want it to be Product name - Description on the same line 
then listed below Attribute 1, Attribute 2 etc

Now I've found the view.html file and then dug a little deeper to find attributes.html however as the page is dynamically generated I can't seem to figure out how to achieve this without renaming all of my products?

Has anyone had this issue before?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 1):

In `app/design/frontend/[Package]/[Theme]/templates/catalog/product/view.phtml`, the Product Title is called using something like this:

```
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?>
```

Your short description is called using something like this:

```
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?>
```

If you're wanting to combine the Description with the Product Name, you can do this:

```
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?> <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getDescription()), 'description') ?>
```

It's essentially the Name and Description outputted onto a single line in the template file.